# Data getting loaded into sqlite database but not getting saved

Tags: android, sqlite

```
<!-- this is my database code -->

package com.example.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper {

 /*     COLUMN NAMES : FOR BEER             */
 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_BRAND = "brand";
 public static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "quantity";
 public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";

 /*     TAG : FOR BEER              */
 private static final String TAG = "BeersDbAdapter";


 private DbHelp mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqldatabase;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Alcohols.db";

 /*     TABLE : FOR BEER                    */
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE_BEER = "Beer_Table";

 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 45;

 private final Context mCtx;

 /*     CREATING TABLE : FOR BEER   */
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
           "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE_BEER + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
            KEY_BRAND + "," +
            KEY_QUANTITY + "," +
            KEY_PRICE + "," +
                  " UNIQUE (" + KEY_BRAND +"));";


 private static class DbHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     DbHelp(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

   /*       CREATING DATABASE: FOR BEER                     */
   Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
   db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    /*      UPGRADING DATABASE : FOR BEER   */
   Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
     + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE_BEER);
   onCreate(db);
  }
 }

 public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 public DatabaseHelper open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DbHelp(mCtx);
  sqldatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }


 public void close() {
  if (mDbHelper != null) {
   mDbHelper.close();
  }
 }

 /*                 FOR BEERS                       */
 public long createBeers(String code, String name, 
   String region) {

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(KEY_BRAND, code);
  initialValues.put(KEY_QUANTITY, name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, region);

  return sqldatabase.insert(SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, null, initialValues);
 }

 public boolean deleteAllBeers() {

  int doneDelete = 0;
  doneDelete = sqldatabase.delete(SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, null , null);
  Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
  return doneDelete > 0;

 }

 public Cursor fetchBeersByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
      Log.w(TAG, inputText);
      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = sqldatabase.query(SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_BRAND, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_PRICE}, 
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = sqldatabase.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_BRAND, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_PRICE}, 
               KEY_BRAND + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

     }

 public Cursor fetchAllBeers() {

     Cursor mCursor = sqldatabase.query(SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
              KEY_BRAND, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_PRICE}, 
        null, null, null, null, null);

      return mCursor;
     }

 /*
 public void insertSomeBeers() {

     createBeers("Natural Ice ","5.9%","130 cals per 12 oz","$0.75");
     createBeers("Budweiser Select ","4.3%","99 cals per 12 oz","$1.45");
     createBeers("Molson Canadian ","5%","148 cals per 12 oz","$1.80");
     createBeers("Becks Pilsner ","5%","138 cals per 12 oz","$1.67");
     createBeers("Amstel Light ","3.5%","95 cals per 12 oz","$2.78");
     createBeers("Bud Select 55 ","2.4%","55 cals per 12 oz","$3.18");
     createBeers("O'Doul's ","0.4%","65 cals per 12 oz","$13.88");

 }
 */

 public Cursor getUserInfo() {

        Cursor cursor = sqldatabase.query(SQLITE_TABLE_BEER, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        return cursor;
    }

 }          

// THIS CLASS IS AN IMPORT EXPORT CLASS
//this is where i have written code to import my excel files into database
package com.example.cheers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.helper.DatabaseHelper;

public class ImportExport {
    DatabaseHelper dbHandler;

    Context context;

    protected static final File DATABASE_DIRECTORY = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImportExport");

    protected static File IMPORT_ITEM_FILE = null;

    /*
    protected static final File IMPORT_ITEM_FILE = new File(DATABASE_DIRECTORY,
            "rates.csv");
            */

    boolean flag = false;

    public ImportExport(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void hello(){
        Log.e("excel", "in exportDatabasecsv()");
    }

    public Boolean exportDataToCSV(String outFileName) {

        Log.e("excel", "in exportDatabasecsv()");
        Boolean returnCode = false;

        String csvHeader = "";
        String csvValues = "";

        try {

            dbHandler = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            dbHandler.open();

            if (!DATABASE_DIRECTORY.exists()) {
                DATABASE_DIRECTORY.mkdirs();
            }
            Log.e("export fun:file name", outFileName);
            File outFile = new File(DATABASE_DIRECTORY, outFileName);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
            Log.e("after FileWriter :file name", outFile.toString());
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

            Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getUserInfo();
            // Log.e("excel", "cursor col count" + cursor.getCount());

            int col_count = cursor.getColumnCount();
            Log.e("col count", ""+col_count);
            csvHeader += "\"" + "Id" + "\",";
            csvHeader += "\"" + "Brand" + "\",";
            csvHeader += "\"" + "Abv" + "\",";
            csvHeader += "\"" + "Cps" + "\",";
            csvHeader += "\"" + "Price" + "\",";

            csvHeader += "\n";

            if (cursor != null) {
                out.write(csvHeader);
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                    //csvValues = Long.toString(cursor.getLong(0)) + ",";
                    Log.e("In getUserInfo()", "_id:"+cursor.getString(0)+",brand:"+cursor.getString(1)+", abv:"+cursor.getString(2)+", cps:"+cursor.getString(3)+", price:"+cursor.getString(4));
                    csvValues  = cursor.getString(0) + ","; //id
                    csvValues += cursor.getString(1) + ","; // name
                    csvValues += cursor.getString(2) + ","; // age
                    csvValues += cursor.getString(3) + ","; // age
                    csvValues += cursor.getString(4) + ",\n"; // age

                    out.write(csvValues);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                // Log.e("excel", "csvValues are:-  " + csvValues);

            }
            out.close();
            cursor.close();
            returnCode = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            returnCode = false;
            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }

        dbHandler.close();
        return returnCode;
    }

    public void test(){
        Log.e("message","hi");
    }

    public boolean importDataFromCSV(boolean flag_is_header_old, String dName) {
        int i = 0;

        boolean flag_is_header = flag_is_header_old;
        /*      FOR DIFFERENT BRANDS OF DRINKS        */
        if(dName == "beer")
        {
          IMPORT_ITEM_FILE = new File(DATABASE_DIRECTORY,
                    "beer.csv");
        }


        File file = new File(IMPORT_ITEM_FILE.getPath());
        if (file.exists()) {
        }
        BufferedReader bufRdr = null;
        try {
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] insertValues = line.split(",");
                if (flag_is_header) {

                    dbHandler = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                    dbHandler.open();
                    //dbHandler.deleteAllBeers();
                    if(dName == "beer")
                    {
                        long row=dbHandler.createBeers(insertValues[1],
                                insertValues[2], insertValues[3]);
                        Log.e("no. of rows inserted", ""+row);
                    }

                    }else {
                        flag_is_header = true;
                    }
                }
                    dbHandler.close();
                    bufRdr.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return flag_is_header;  
            }


        }

// THIS IS MY CODE FROM WHERE I AM CALLING THE IMPORTEXPORT CLASS
package com.example.cheers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.helper.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.model.SpinnerNavItem;

public class DrinksActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
{
    // action bar
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Title navigation Spinner data
    private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> navSpinner;

    // Navigation adapter
    private TitleNavigationAdapter adapter;

    /*      FOR EXCEL   */
    boolean flag_is_header_old=false;
    boolean flag_is_header_new=false;
    boolean if_new = false;
    ImportExport importexport;
    DatabaseHelper databaseConnector;
    Context context;
    String dName="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drinks);
        /*          EXCEL           */
        initializeUI();
        /*      for navigation menu     */
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Hide the action bar title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Back Button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Spinner dropdown navigation
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Spinner title navigation data
        navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Drinks", R.drawable.drinkicon));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Home", R.drawable.home));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Recipes", R.drawable.recipesicon));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem("Remedy", R.drawable.remedyicon));    
        // title drop down adapter
        adapter = new TitleNavigationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navSpinner);

        // assigning the spinner navigation     
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);

        /*   end of navigation menu   */

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        try
        {
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    if(if_new==false)
                    {
                        dName = "beer";
                        try
                        {
                        databaseConnector.deleteAllBeers();
                        flag_is_header_new = importexport.importDataFromCSV(flag_is_header_old,dName);
                        if(flag_is_header_new==true)
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "File imported successfully", 1).show();
                            Log.i("Drinks : ImportBeer", "File imported successfully");
                            callB();
                        }
                            if_new=false;
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Import Unsuccessful", 1).show();
                            Log.e("Drinks : ImportBeer", "Import Unsuccessful");
                            Log.d("Drinks : ImportBeer", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        callB();
                    }
                    flag_is_header_new = false;
                    dName = "";
                }
            }
        });
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Drinks : GridView", "Error with gridview onclick");
            Log.d("Drinks : GridView", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*      FOR EXCEL   */
    public void initializeUI()
      {
        context=this;
        databaseConnector=new DatabaseHelper(context);
        importexport=new ImportExport(context);
      }


    /*      FOR EXCEL   */
    public void callB(){
        try
        {
        Intent iB = new Intent(DrinksActivity.this, BeerActivity.class);
        startActivity(iB);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Drinks : callV()", "Error with callB() onclick");
            Log.d("Drinks : callB()", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    }

    /*      OPTIONS MENU        */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /*      OPTIONS MENU        */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about_us:
            callAboutUs();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_contact_us:
            // check for updates action
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
         return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    } 

    public void callAboutUs(){
        Intent iA = new Intent(DrinksActivity.this,AboutUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(iA);
    }

    /*      OPTIONS MENU : LOCATION SERVICE         */

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            items.add(new Item("Beer", R.drawable.vishal2));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if(v == null)
            {
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_image_adapter, viewGroup, false);
               v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
               v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);

            return v;
        }

        private class Item
        {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(itemPosition == 0)
        {
            try
            {
            Intent i = new Intent(DrinksActivity.this, DrinksActivity.class);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
                {
                Log.e("Drinks : onNavigationItemSelected", "Error with onNavigationItemSelected onclick");
                Log.d("Drinks : onNavigationItemSelected", e.getMessage());
                }
        }

            return false;
    }
}

// and this is the code from where i am calling the display method of databse
package com.example.cheers;

import com.example.helper.DatabaseHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class WhsikeyRecipeList extends Activity {

public DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
public SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
String value2 = "Whiskey";
Cursor cursor;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_whsikey_recipe_list);
  /*FOR TITLE*/
  //Typeface font;
  //TextView text;
  //text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brand);
  //font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Outwrite.ttf");
  //text.setTypeface(font);

  dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
  dbHelper.open();
  //fillBeerList();
  //Clean all data
  //dbHelper.deleteAllBeers();
  //Add some data
  //dbHelper.insertSomeBeers();

  //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
  displayListView();


 }

 /*     OPTIONS MENU        */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.whsikey_recipe_list, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /*      OPTIONS MENU        */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about_us:
            callAboutUs();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_contact_us:
            // check for updates action
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void callAboutUs(){
        Intent iA = new Intent(WhsikeyRecipeList.this,AboutUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(iA);
    }

 public void displayListView() {
 try
 {
     //cursor = dbHelper.getWRecipesInfo();
     cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllWRecipes();
 }
catch(Exception e)
 {
     Log.e("WhsikeyRecipeList : Cursor", "Error calling getWRecipesInfo()");
     Log.d("WhsikeyRecipeList : Cursor:getWRecipesInfo()", e.getMessage()); 
 } 

  // The desired columns to be bound
  String[] columns = new String[] {
    DatabaseHelper.WhiskyRecipes_NAME
  };

  // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
  int[] to = new int[] { 
    R.id.brecipes_name
  };

  <!-- create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
  as well as the layout information-->
  dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, R.layout.activity_database_helper, 
    cursor, 
    columns, 
    to,
    0);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
     int position, long id) {
   // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
   Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

   // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
   String countryCode = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wrecipes_name"));
    try
      {
          getWhiskeyDetails(countryCode);
      }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Log.e("WhsikeyRecipeList : setOnItemClickListener", "Error calling getWhiskeyDetails()");
         Log.d("WhsikeyRecipeList : setOnItemClickListener: getWhiskeyDetails()", e.getMessage()); 
     }
    /*
     finally
     {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Log.e("countryCode", countryCode);
     }
    */
   }
  });

  EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
  myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
    dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
   }
  });

  dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
         public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
             return dbHelper.fetchWRecipesByName(constraint.toString());
         }
     });
 }
     public void getWhiskeyDetails(String countryCode){
         String data = countryCode;
         Log.d("displayListView:BeerRecipeList", countryCode);
         try
         {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(WhsikeyRecipeList.this,AlcoholListTitles.class);
         myIntent.putExtra("whiskeyTitle", data);
         myIntent.putExtra("recipeTitle", value2);
         startActivity(myIntent);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.e("WhsikeyRecipeList : getWhiskeyDetails()", "Error calling AlcoholListTitles");
             Log.d("WhsikeyRecipeList : getWhiskeyDetails(): AlcoholListTitles class", e.getMessage()); 
         }
     }
}


//... when i am commenting out the import line and trying to load the data from the database //after i have first imported the data... d data is not getting displayed
```

// y does this happen..any specific reason...please help me find out
// I think somewhere the database is getting updated , so becuase of that the data i which i had //previously loaded from excel into tables, is getting deleted
// please help me figure out the probem

Comment: Have you defined `Data Type` for your column fields while create a table??

Comment: You do not specify any types for columns inside table SQLITE_TABLE_BEER in DATABASE_CREATE string.

Comment: //reply to the answers given to my question

> Blockquote

when i am importing the data(through excel sheets .csv format) gets saved into database and gets displayed...
but when i comment out the line that is importing the excel file and trying to get d data for display from database...it isnt showing any data
so i think somewhere the database is getting re-created and hence d data previously loaded is getting deleted.
please help